# Open screenshot in Robotframework log.html on Jenkins (Robotframework plugin)

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins, robotframework, screenshot

here is my problem:

I can launch a jenkins job which launches an automated Test. When this job fails and I go to the log.html, I don't see the screenshots. However when I go to the folder that hosts my Jenkins in localhost, and I open my log.html file, the screenshots appear correctly. Can you tell me why I can't see them on Jenkins please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1RJr.png)

I tried to configure output path in Jenkins but nothing change this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyTMP.png)

Thanks for reading this :)

Comment: Can you share a bit more details. What keyword do you use to capture screenshot? Share some code example.

Comment: try just putting *.png, also it will copy data only from robot result directory.